# Accrual some interest on a time basis in all the accounts registered

Tags: time-triggered

Let's say that I have to accrual some interest on a daily basis in all the accounts registered, and that the value actually depends on user activity. For instance, users that made more transactions in the last 7 days get more.

How would you implement that?

- some external process daily calling a single action on the contract that "for eachs" over all accounts and recent blocks? Can a contract even list all recently received transactions?
- some external process that reads the chain, does all the math and sends individual transfer actions to each account when appropriated?
- some other?